# Xcode Import For Localizations Missing Resource in Import error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, localization

After having our app translated in a few languages, we realized that there were a couple `.strings` files that had been included in the `.xliff` files that were not needed to be translated, so they could be deleted.

So, I unchecked the localization option for those languages in Xcode and deleted the .string files.

However, now whenever I import a .xliff file it still somehow things in it missing localization for those files we don't want anymore.

[image]

Importing will crash Xcode.

Even doing an Export for Localizations will reference those .strings files that are nowhere anymore.

**Where in our Xcode project could those files be still referenced? I can't import localizations until I get this fixed.**

Comment: Are you able to fix this problem?Same scenario i faced.

Comment: @Verma - I ended up removing all the `NSLocalizedStringFromTable` and replaced them with `NSLocalizedString`. That worked for me.

Comment: I was able to just press import and it got imported without any problem. For me that was the only error message there. I am using iOS 11 though, Apple may have fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue, for me it was caused by incorrect paths in *xliff* itself.

Check the *original* attribute in **file**s

```
<file original="..." source-language="en" target-language="cs">
```

for me it has the path that included the root directory (e.g. "**ProjectDir**/Resources/..." instead of "Resources/..."). This blocked import.

### In your case

I assume you'll have to go through xliff files and find  that reference strings that you deleted and remove such blocks (`<file original="path/to/deleted.strings">...</file>`)

### In general

I've written a simple bash script that expects all affected files as arguments and modifies the *original* attribute in case contains invalid path:

```
for file in "$@"
do
   sed -i '' -E "s#original=\"**ProjectDir**/#original=\"#g" "$file"
done
```

Replace **ProjectDir** with whatever your root folder is (or any extra parent folders) and it will be trimmed.

**Note that it will edit passed files, so make sure you have a backup**.